# c# skipping while loop

Tags: c#, oracle, wcf, while-loop

in debugging my wcf call its skipping the while loop and not reading the internal data. I've been bouncing through SO and msdn for help and nothing seems to stand out.  Anyone have any clues as to what I'm missing or doing to cause this loop to not iterate through?

**Solution: this was a DB problem, once I updated the Oracle DB values the query ran in SQL developer and debugging is working in VS2010.**

Thanks

```
            using (connection)
        {
            try {
                connection.ConnectionString = connString;
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sqlString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read()) {

                    td.TNAME = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? " " : reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

                    td.TASK = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? " " : reader.GetValue(1).ToString();

                    td.STATUS = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? " " : reader.GetValue(2).ToString();

                    td.COMPLETE = reader.IsDBNull(3) ? " " : reader.GetValue(3).ToString();

                    td.PRIORITY = reader.IsDBNull(4) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(4));

                    tl.Add(td);
                }
            //while (reader.NextResult());

            reader.Close();
            } catch (Exception ex)  {
                myErr = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        return tl;
```

Comment: What is your query statement? Just run the query and check how many records showing in Oracle

Comment: If it doesn't go into the `while` I guess that `reader.Read()` returns `false`. Did you try debugging to see if you get any data in the first place? Also that `catch` looks like it is swallowing any exceptions, unless you are checking `myErr` somewhere later on. Are you sure your connection is open, for example.

Comment: yes the sql statement works in SQL Developer, your right the reader.HasRows and reader.Read is null. My connection is open but that has to be where the problem is.  Thanks for pointing me in the proper direction. I'm also moving the catch down, I'll post back the answers once I correct this. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're actually getting to the while statement without execptions, then the obvious answer is that your datareader has no data. Try examining the value of [`reader.HasRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before the while loop. I imagine it will be false. Does your sql statement actually return data in SQL Developer?

Comment: yes the sql statement works in SQL Developer, I'll check the reader.HasRows now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for the loop to not execute:

1. There is an exception from the code that precedes the loop.
2. `reader.Read()` doesn't return any data.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if your loop never executes then there is no data returned from the query, but I see another problem in your code. The variable `td` is never re-initialized and in every loop you add to the list the same variable updated with the values extracted from the current loop values.

So you end with the value of the last loop in your tl (whatever is it)

I think you should write

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    td = new YourTDClass();  // Create a new instance of an element of td class

    td.TNAME = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? " " : reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    td.TASK = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? " " : reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
    td.STATUS = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? " " : reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
    td.COMPLETE = reader.IsDBNull(3) ? " " : reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
    td.PRIORITY = reader.IsDBNull(4) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(4));
    tl.Add(td);
}
```

Comment: every time I see code like `IsDBNull(0) ? ...` I yearn for a null coalescing operator that works against DBNull.Value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write more easily:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
while(dr.Read())
{
   var value = new YourClass { 

      propClassString =    dr.GetString(0),     //for string
      propClassInt =       dr.GetInt32(1),      //for int
      propClassDateTime =  dr.GetDateTime(2)    //for datetime
            
    };        
    list.Add(value);
}
return list;
```